# Save PDF to File using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, pdf, chromium, puppeteer

I'm using the puppeteer to get a PDF using the Fetch API and save the file to disk.

I'm trying to save a PDF to a file on disk but when I open the pdf I see a white screen.

[image]

[image]

**!!Edited!!**

Found a solution here https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/299#issuecomment-340199753

Comment: Viewing the robo2 file in a hex editor might help as it could be a text file and not a valid pdf.

Answer (score 13):

```
await page.pdf({ path: 'path/to/save/pdf', format: 'A4' });
```

This will save the PDF in to disk.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using Puppeteer already, the best way to save a webpage to PDF is just to open it using Puppeteer and then using the Puppeteer API to save the PDF.

The `page.pdf()` function does just that. [See docs](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-pagepdfoptions).

I'm assuming that by using `fetch()`, you're only downloading the `getPdf.asp` which doesn't by itself produce a valid PDF response stream. Perhaps it only responds with a client side HTML including a script that fetches the PDF from some remote resource.

I would thus try:

```
await page.goto(PDF_PAGE_URL);
const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf();
// process the buffer
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: how to process the buffer to stream the response?

Comment: Are you sure? I got this error instead:
net::ERR_ABORTED at https://

Answer (score 1):

#### Backend

---

If you add the path option to the `page.pdf()` it will save directly to the disk where the server is hosted.

#### Frontend

---

If you return the pdf buffer from the server `page.pdf()` and send it to client / front-end. You will have to process the pdf.

```js
...
 const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({
   printBackground: true,
   format: 'A4',
 });
 res.send(pdfBuffer);
...
```

Say you have a route `/download` which will return the pdf buffer from puppeteer's `page.pdf()` option. And on front-end you have a button with id 'download` to process the stream. Here's how you would do it

1. Processing the buffer
2. Creating an ObjectURL with that buffer.
3. Create an `a` tag which points the `href` to the object url.
4. Add download attribute and mimic a fake click to that link.
5. Binding the download button to the handler function's 'click' event.

### Code

```js
function handleClick() {
    fetch('/download')
        .then((res) => res.blob()) // --- 1.
        .then((readableStream) => {
            const blob = new Blob([readableStream], { type: 'application/pdf' }); // --- 1.
            blobToSaveAs('invoice', blob); // --- 2.
        })
        .catch((e) => console.error(e));
}

function blobToSaveAs(fileName, blob) {
    try {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); // --- 2.
        const link = document.createElement('a'); // --- 3.
        if (link.download !== undefined) {
            link.setAttribute('href', url); // --- 3.
            link.setAttribute('download', fileName); // --- 4.
            link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click(); // --- 4.
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('BlobToSaveAs error', e);
    }
}

document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', handleClick); // --- 5.
```